# How to use known values ​in odeint?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

[Attached an analytical solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3OG8.jpg)
I need to solve a problem: Suppose that the fish population P(t) in a lake is attacked by a disease at time t = 0, with the result that the fish cease to reproduce (so that the birth rate is β = 0) and the death rate δ (deaths per week per fish) is thereafter proportional to 1/√P. If there were initially 900 fish in the lake and 441 were left after 6 weeks, how long did it take all the fish in the lake to die? 
I don’t understand how to add the condition P (6) = 441?

```py
r=np.array([6])
p=np.array([441])
def fun (y , t, r, k):
    P=y
    dydt = -k*math.sqrt(P)
    return dydt
y0 = np.array([900])
t = np.linspace(1, 9, 9)
sol = odeint (fun, y0, t, args = (p, r))
print(sol)
```

Comment: This is more like a boundary value problem, to be solved with `solve_bvp`. Or you could establish the ODE for the inverse function `t(P)`, `t'(P)=-1/(k*sqrt(P))`, which transforms this problem into a simple integration and corresponds to the method of separation of variables. But then you could also directly find the explicit solution, which would be off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The general-purpose approach is to use a non-linear system solver like `scipy.optimize.fsolve` where you encode all your conditions in a system function and hope for the best. The system is

```py
def f(x):
    k,T = x;
    P = odeint(lambda P,t: -k*abs(P)**0.5, 900, [0,6,T]);
    return [ P[1,0]-441, P[2,0] ]

spo.fsolve(f,[1,12])
```

This returns the parameters

```
k,T = [ 3.00000001, 19.99998371]
```

Adjusting the error tolerances of the integrator and solver will increase the accuracy of the resulting parameters.